# R - Removing text between quotes from a string

Tags: r, regex, stringr, grepl

I have a number of lines, each are processed individually (no need for a loop here). Here are examples of my lines:

```
"warning(\"Failed to parse headers:\\n\", paste0(bad, \"\\n\"), call. = FALSE)"
"}"
"names <- vapply(pieces, \"[[\", 2, FUN.VALUE = character(1))"
"new_response <- grepl(\"^HTTP\", lines)"
"header_lines <- lines[lines != \'\'][-1]"
```

As you can see, the lines are bits of code.

**Problem:** I need to remove anything that is between quotes, either double (`""`), or simple (`''`) quotes.

I did the following:

```
# First, get a list of all strings in the line
text_quotes <-  regmatches(line, gregexpr('"([^"]*)"', line))[[1]] # double quoes ""
text_quotes <- c(text_quotes, regmatches(line, gregexpr("'([^']*)'", line))[[1]]) # single quotes ''

# Remove the empty ones
text_quotes <- stringi::stri_remove_empty(text_quotes, na_empty = TRUE)
      
# Now, we can clean up the line
line_no_strings <- line
      if(length(text_quotes) > 0) 
        line_no_strings <- mgsub::mgsub(line, text_quotes, rep("", times = length(text_quotes)))
```

My problem is, some quotes (I don't know how to call the "bits" that are inside quotes) may match a regex, and then `mgsub` can't find them.

Problematic example:

```
"names <- vapply(pieces, \"[[\", 2, FUN.VALUE = character(1))"
```

One of the "quotes" for that one is `\"[[\"`. When I run it, it fails miserably with the below:

```
 Error in gregexpr(pattern[i], string, ...) : 
  invalid regular expression '"[["', reason 'Missing ']''
```

**Edit:** The expected output would be (for each line of the above, the problematic case is in the middle):

```
"warning(, paste0(bad, ), call. = FALSE)"
"}"
"names <- vapply(pieces, , 2, FUN.VALUE = character(1))"
"new_response <- grepl(, lines)"
"header_lines <- lines[lines != ][-1]"
```

I am sensing there should be a way of doing this *without* extracting first, so that R's regex don't freak out on me. Yet I stand defeated in front of the regexes once again.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: `gsub("[\"'].*['\"]","",your_String)`?

Comment: @Onyambu I just added the expected output. The gsub you put isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gsub("[\"'].*?['\"]","", a)

[1] "warning(, paste0(bad, ), call. = FALSE)"               
[2] "}"                                                     
[3] "names <- vapply(pieces, , 2, FUN.VALUE = character(1))"
[4] "new_response <- grepl(, lines)"                        
[5] "header_lines <- lines[lines != ][-1]"
```

where

```
a <- c("warning(\"Failed to parse headers:\\n\", paste0(bad, \"\\n\"), call. = FALSE)", 
        "}", "names <- vapply(pieces, \"[[\", 2, FUN.VALUE = character(1))", 
        "new_response <- grepl(\"^HTTP\", lines)", "header_lines <- lines[lines != ''] [-1]")
```